# What agent is this nagios host using (if any)

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I disabled nrpe via `service nrpe stop`.  It is not running.  Neither is snmpd running.  I still have seen the status checks for disk space, ping, http, etc all running for this host.  How do I determine what agent or method is being used to communicate between the nagios host and server?  Is there another way for nagios to run these plugins?  nrpe is not configured under xinetd if you were wondering.

Comment: IIRC, it's possible to configure the Nagios host to SSH into the monitored host and remotely execute plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An agent is only needed for "internal" checks like disk space, load, etc. It is not needed for ping, http, and other network-accessible services.

It's possible that it's using [check_by_ssh](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_by_ssh), or that it's misconfigured and is really just checking disk space on the nagios box itself.

Look at the service definition in question, and find the check command. If it includes "check_by_ssh", there's your answer. If not, go find the command definition that matches that command name to see what is really going on.